# Choosing sample points for polynomial regression to improve accuracy

Tags: regression, machine-learning

An online set of slides [  [link](http://www.ai.mit.edu/courses/6.867-f04/lectures/lecture-4-ho.pdf#page=4), start on page 4] describes the following situation: we're doing polynomial regression using the model

$$\texttt{prediction}(x) := w_0 + w_1x + \dotsb + w_kx^k + \epsilon \qquad \epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)\quad (\sigma^2 \text{ known})$$

And we assume that the function that generated the training data (call it $y(x)$) actually **is** a function of the above form. We consider which points $x_1, \dotsc x_m$ are the best values to sample for training such that we can improve the accuracy of the optimal guess $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \mathbf{y}$.

$$\text{Here } X:= \begin{bmatrix}1 & x_1 & x_1^2 & 
\dotsb & x_m^k\\ \vdots \\ 1 & x_m & x_m^2 & \dotsc & x_m^k\end{bmatrix}$$

He describes choosing $x_i$ to minimize $\det \left((A^TA)^{-1} \right)$ since the variance of the guess depends on that quantity. The slides don't go into a ton of depth, but he mentions using "sequential selection" to choose the next sample point in an online learning method.

**Specific question:** I tried to follow up on this by searching on Google Scholar and Google for "sequential selection" "polynomial regression" and didn't get anywhere. Is there another more standard term for this?

**General question:** Where can I read more about how the selection of points affects properties of the feature matrix $X$, and functions of $X$? I'm particularly interested in feature normalization and how it affects the condition number of $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword is "Design of Experiments". What you are describing is a [D-optimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_design#Minimizing_the_variance_of_estimators) design. The question of finding optimal points to do prediction started allegedly 1747 and there exists a ton of literature. Worthwhile mentioning is [Pukelsheim](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898719109). If you are more into computer experiments you might want to look at [Fang](https://www.crcpress.com/Design-and-Modeling-for-Computer-Experiments/Fang-Li-Sudjianto/p/book/9781584885467). A modern overview (which goes beyond classical designs) is freely available at [Pronzato/Müller](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00685876/document).

If conditioning of the design matrix is an issue instead of using "raw" polynomials, you might want to read about "orthogonal polynomials" in regression .